# What is the reason of padding / margin?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have been impementing a web page in HTML and I have came across a weird problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/SntpD/3/

```
#menuh
    {
    width:100%;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    font-family:arial, tahoma;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:12%;
    background:#c1188d;
    }
```

I can't see anything here which should introduce the white margin on the left side.

The magenta belt for drop-down menu is supposed to be aligned strictly to left (in my opinion) but it is not. (left side should be like it's right side is to right edge.)

Could somebody tell me what is the distance between edge of browser and magenta div (#menuh) ?

Comment: Question title does not match question.

Comment: @BoltClock why would you think so, and what is your proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are default styles imposed by many browsers. In my case (Chrome/Mac), the `body` element has a margin imposed on it of 8px. You can use the following rule (put it at the top of your css) to remove all margin/padding on elements by default:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

Or you can just remove the margin/padding on the `body` element. I prefer the wildcard method, since it keeps the same issue from coming up later with other browser defaults.

Comment: To add to this answer, most experienced web UI developers use what is known as a CSS reset to remove default browser behaviors, before applying their own CSS styles.  I would highly recommend looking into CSS resets, as these can make your life much easier, particularly for cross-browser development

Comment: Actually, most experienced web UI developers don't.

Comment: I find myself agreeing with BoltClock here

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle (and most browsers) give the `<body>` tag a default padding, which is the white space you're seeing. Set

```
body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

and your problem goes away. The padding in your JSFiddle (for me on Chrome/Win8 at least) is 8px.

To catch all situations (browsers have different default styles), apply a 0 padding *and margin* to both `<body>` and `<html>`:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default padding is the issue. Most all browsers have it, so even outside of jsfiddle, you may encounter it.

Best thing to do is use a CSS reset stylesheet. Creates proper padding and margin reset for most of the elements you will use in your web page. Here are some examples:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
http://www.cssreset.com/
http://html5reset.org/
http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/